# How do get value tag in Ruby using regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the tag:

```
val = "<a href=\"https://mobile.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Mobile Web</a>"
```

In my test:

```
val[/(>.*<)/]
```

The return:

```
>Mobile Web<
```

I want return the text:

```
Mobile Web
```

Comment: Rule one, [don't use regular expressions to parse HTML or XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). While it's tempting, it's also extremely error-prone and fragile. Instead, use a real parser. It's quite easy, more stable and less fragile. @Blender gave you the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lookahead/lookbehind will work.

```
val[/(?<=>)(.*)(?=<)/]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can parse it with [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/):

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Mobile Web</a>'
elem = Nokogiri(html)

puts elem.text
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one.  Regexp is the wrong tool for parsing html.

Comment: It's a shame the OP didn't give a real world-example of HTML; As is the true strength of a parser like Nokogiri isn't apparent, nor is the failings of using a regex. We have no idea what machinations were gone through to extract that line, but for real world use it'd be easy with a real parser.

Comment: Nokogiri is great! In big application, this less performance! I prefer regex!

Comment: @DarlanDieterich: Benchmark it and tell me how much slower a HTML parser is. I really, really doubt your use case calls for a regex solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can use match and select the parts you want with the parenthesis

```
/>(.*)</.match(val)[1]
```

I would use a html parsing library like hpricot or nokogiri for html parsing though because there can be a lot of corner cases with regex that aren't apparent until after it's running in production somewhere for months and breaks!

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Mobile Web</a>'
elem = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html).child

p elem.text #=> Mobile Web
```